# Add Fragment dependent on a Loader result

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-sqlite, loader

My goal is to write a messenger Activity. Right now there are two kinds of Messages implemented: 
 - Simple Text 
 - Gallery 
In my messenger Activity I use the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks functions in order to asynchronically query the Messages table in my DB. That query returns (amongst other information): 
 - What kind of Message is it (Simple Text or Gallery) 
 - What is the ID of that data in the type-specific table (Gallery leads to a table full of pictures, for example) 
Now I have a Fragment for Simple Text and one for Gallery. Those need the data's ID and then use a Loader to query its table in the DB. Ideally I would just dynamically add that type-specific Fragment for every message I have. 

In pseudo code:

```
function allMessagesAreLoaded() {
    for (message : messages) {
        if message is simpleTextMessage then
            add simpleTextMessageFragment
        else if message is gallery then
            add galleryFragment
        end if
    }
}
```

Now to my question:
It is not best practice to use Fragments in this case according to this source: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html 
What is the way to go to have an encapsulated layout and function set/class that can be programmatically added during runtime depending on a DB query result? 
Maybe I'm looking at it from the wrong direction. I have no experience in creating Android user interfaces. Any tip/point in the right direction will help me a lot :-) 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a good solution but this is what I did now: 
I took everything that I had in the Fragment and put it in a separate class. I handover the Context and LoaderManager from the Activity to the class-object when I create it. It works that way and my code is encapsulated. The Activity has a lot less code. So with that I reached my goal, there's probably a better way though, I guess.